# $f(x+1)=f(x)+\ln(x+1)$ , $f $ convex

Tags: real-analysis, recurrence-relations

let $f$ a convex function on the iterval $I=]-1,+\infty[$ :

$f(x+1)=f(x)+\ln(x+1)$

I have proved that for all natural numbers:

$f(x)=f(x+n)-\ln(\prod_{k=1}^{n} (x+k))$

and I have proved that:

$\lim_{x\to+\infty} f'_+(x) -f'_-(x)=0$

How to prove that $f$
is differentiable on the interval $I$

i think that we should prove that:

$\lim_{x\to a} f'_+(x) -f'_-(x)=0$ for all $a \in I$

Please help me with this question

Comment: This is a repost of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4836522 Please delete one of them.

Comment: Why making a duplicate of your own post?

Comment: my first post included an error which i didn't see after a long time

Comment: @AnneBauval i couldn't delete the first post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$f(x+1)=f(x)+\ln(x+1) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4836522/fx1-fx-lnx1)

Comment: Hint: [Bohr-Mollerup theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem).

Comment: I think you *can* delete the first post. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24941/how-to-delete-posts-on-the-site

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=ln(g(x))$
$$
g(x+1)=(x+1)g(x)
$$

But since f is logarithmically complex convex and follows the above equation it must be a variant of $\Gamma(x)$ function by [Bohr-Mollerup theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem)

Edit: just saw @gonçalo's comment after posting

Comment: This happens with me all the time. :-)

Comment: here i was feeling all proud i remembered that xD